# Fiware and IDAS: Issue with SendObsevations.py

Tags: python, fiware, fiware-orion

I am very new with IDAS y Fiware. I am working with the Figway (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-figway) and I have a problem when I tried to send observations with this command:

```
python SendObservation.py sensor001x 't|23'
```

This is the response:

```
* Asking to http://130.206.80.43:7896/iot/d?k=4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov&i=sensor001x
* Headers: {'Fiware-Service': 'OpenIoT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Fiware-ServicePath': '/', 'X-Auth-Token': 'NULL'}
* Sending PAYLOAD: 
t|23

...

* Status Code: 400
* Response: 
{"name":"UNSUPPORTED_TYPE","message":"The request content didn't have the expected type [text/plain ]"}
```

Could you help me with that? Where I am wrong? I working with a RaspberryPi.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that could be related with the cause of the problem, but using `Content-Type: application/json` while the actual payload is not JSON (it is `t|23`, which I understand corresponds to text/plain) seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, It should be "Content-type: text/plain"